# Combinatorics problem: distinguishable and indistinguishable choosers, why does it matter?

Tags: combinatorics

I need some clarification regarding this question:

What is the number of possibilities to divide a class of 42 students between 6 teachers, such that two teachers will teach 8 students each, three teachers will teach 7 students each, and the 6'th teacher will teach 5 students (We distinguish between the teachers).

The book says it's: ${42 \choose 8}{34 \choose 8}{26 \choose 7}{19 \choose 7}{12 \choose 7}{5 \choose 5}$

And I was able to get to it too, but what I don't understand is why was it important to them to say that "We distinguish between the teachers"? Why should I care, and what does it mean, anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $2$ students are divided over $2$ teachers. Each teacher gets $1$ student.

Then - if you distinguish the teachers - there are $\binom21\binom11=2$ possibilities.

If you do not distinguish teachers then there is only $1$ possibility: each teacher (no matter who) gets a student and that's it.

Comment: Great example, thanks.

Comment: I am glad this worked for you. Things might get even more clear if only one student must be divided over two teachers. Who is the lucky teacher then? Does it matter (teachers distinguishable) or not (teachers not distinguishable)?

Comment: @drhab: so if we didn't distinguish between teachers, we'd need to divide through $6!$?

Comment: @drhab correct me if I'm wrong, but if the teachers are indistinguishable, then the answer is 0 (because there's no way to divide 1 student between two teachers), but if they are distinguishable, then the answer is 2 (either the first teacher gets a student and the second does not, or the second gets the student and the first does not).

Comment: I agree with the second part of your comment (distinghuisable) but not with the first (indistinghuisable). No way to divide one student if you have two teachers at your disposal? You can just hand him over to one of the teachers (which of the two doesn't matter here). So there is one way.